# Getting memory location from getattr()

Tags: python, memory, getattr, getattribute

from my research, I understand that using `getattr()` allows one to get a method on a certain object such as:

```
getattr(obj, method)
```

is the equivalent to

```
obj.method()
```

However, I tried to use it in my code and the statement returns a memory location:

```
<bound method _Class.method of <Class instance at 0x7f412df0c320>>
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `getattr(obj, 'method')` is the equivalent of `obj.method`. Nothing is called, you are simply retrieving the attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods are just attributes, and `getattr()` retrieves attributes. As such

```
getattr(obj, 'method')
```

is the same as

```
obj.method
```

so without the `()` call primary, so no call to the method object made. Just add a call expression, to call the result of the `getattr()` method:

```
getattr(obj, 'method')()
```

`__getattr__` is a hook method to allow a class to customise how missing attributes are handled. You should generally not need to call it directly.